# ¿Cómo declarar un ArrayList con valores?

Tags: java, arraylist

En el caso de los arrays uno puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
int array[]={1,2,3,4};
```

Pero, ¿En el caso de un ArrayList cómo sería?
Hasta ahora lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrayList.add(1);
arrayList.add(2);
arrayList.add(3);
arrayList.add(4);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En realidad, se puede hacer a partir un *arreglo* (o *matriz*) con la ayuda de la clase `java.util.Arrays`:

```
// Lista inmutable
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

```
// Lista mutable
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```